# Multiply every entry in column by a fixed number in SQL

Tags: sql

In SQL, say I have a table of the following layout:

```
id    name      age
1     george    12
2     tom       14
3     charles   19
4     henry     21
5     fiona     12
6     kate      14
...
```

If I discover that I've made a terrible inputting mistake, and that everybody is actually twice their age, is there a way to multiply the `age` column by 2 in one sweep instead of needing to painstakingly go through the whole column and edit each age individually (pretend I have 500 entries so manual work is out of the question).

Is there a SQL solution?

Comment: +1: I needed to know this for converting a column from a value in minutes to a value in seconds. In this case, there was no mistake, just an upgrade in resolution. All the existing values were correct, they just had to be multiplied by 60.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's really easy:

```
UPDATE table SET age=age*2
```

Comment: Based on the phrasing of the question I'm guessing this is a homework problem. In reality such an error would have introduced rounding/truncation issues and the original ages could not be restored by a simple doubling. You'll notice that nobody has an odd-numbered age after the "correction". So if this is real data then you'll want to re-calculate from scratch.

Comment: In reality, nobody would ever store ages in a database, they'd store birth dates. Regardless, my answer and the one below are both sufficient for this question.

Comment: I wasn't critiquing your answer at all. It just seemed that adding the information to the approved answer was the appropriate place. The "you"s in my comment were directed to future readers. Sorry if that seemed confusing.

Comment: No problem. I probably shouldn't have even left a comment, but anyway thanks for the tip. It's a good one. Rounding errors could easily be a problem, but of course you're right, this is obviously homework.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, run an `update`:

```
update theTable set age = age * 2
```

Depending on the settings in the database, you might not be allowed to run an `update` without a `where` (to protect against mistakes), then you would add a dummy comparison:

```
update theTable set age = age * 2 where 1 = 1
```

Comment: Hell, that was obvious. I knew that you could do addition like that but never thought SQL was clever enough to do multiplication too.