# PostgreSQL: How do I multiply every entry in multiple columns by a fixed number?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Okay, my question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022999/multiply-every-entry-in-column-by-a-fixed-number-in-sql) but my case is different. In my PostgreSQL 9.5 database, I have a table `my_table` having a layout like follows:

```
ID   a0   a1 ..   a23   b0   b1   ..   b23   c0   c1 ..   c23
1    23   22 ..   11    12   0.12 ..   65   0.17  12 ..   19
2    42   52 ..   12    1.2  14   ..   42   0.35  12 ..   12
3    11   25 ..   13    2.5  0.14 ..   15   1.1   8  ..   14
```

First column `ID (integer)` is unique for each record while there are 24 columns `(numeric)` for each variable `a`, `b` and `c` thus summing up to 72 columns. I want to multiply each entry in these 72 columns to a fixed number, let say 0.20. I am aware of PostgreSQL `UPDATE` command like this:

```
UPDATE my_table set a0 = a0 * 0.20
```

In this case, I would need to repeat this command a large number of times (undesired). Is there an alternate quick approach (single `SELECT` or iteration) to multiply a fixed number to multiple columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example table:

```
drop table if exists my_table;
create table my_table(id serial primary key, a1 dec, a2 dec, a3 dec);
insert into my_table values
(default, 1, 2, 3);
```

Use [execute](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) in an [anonymous code block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html):

```
do $$
begin
    execute concat('update my_table set ', string_agg(format('%1$I = %1$I * 0.2', attname), ','))
    from pg_attribute a
    where attrelid = 'my_table'::regclass
    and attnum > 0
    and attname ~ '^[abc]+';
end
$$;

select * from my_table;

 id | a1  | a2  | a3  
----+-----+-----+-----
  1 | 0.2 | 0.4 | 0.6
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thank you! You are a life saver :)